# Bootstrap dialog not closing on calling modal('hide')

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6

In the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a9wcee

I am showing a `Bootstrap` dialog when the application starts. But the dialog box doesn't close on clicking the close button. What am I doing wrong?

In `index.html`, I create the application's root component and pass an attribute which shows in the dialog box

```
<my-app signup="startup message">loading </my-app>
```

In `app.component.ts`, in `ngAfterViewInit`, I read the attribute and show the dialog box (after calling `setTimeout` as I need to wait for change detection to finish before)

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){

    this.signup = this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('signup');

    setTimeout(()=>this.isSignupProcess());
  }
```

`app.component.html` has a dialog box component

```
  Hope to see dialog when the application starts!  

      <button>Am I clickable</button>
      <app-dialog-box #dialogBox [dialogMessage]="" [dialogID]="'appDialog'" [context]=""></app-dialog-box>
```

The dialog box component is a `Bootstrap` modal.

```
<div class="modal" #modal tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="someID">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Example</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{dialogMessage}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="dialogHide()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the dialog component also has functions to show and hide the modal.

```
dialogShow(message:string,context:DialogContext){

   this.context = context;
    this.dialogMessage = message;
    //console.log("dialog show called ");
    $(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('show');

  }

  dialogHide(){
   // console.log("dialog hide called");
    $(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('hide');
  }
}
```

But `dialogHide` doesn't hide the modal. Why?